# gdal_translate does not crop the GeoTIFF file

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, osgeo

When I use gdal_translate to crop the GeoTiff file, the output file is saving the same as the input file. Nothing changed. The size needs to decrease at the boundaries I specify. What can I do?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os  

os.system('gdal_translate -projwin 3046477.80 4645536.98 3046546.08 4645571.24 input.tif output.tif')
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of `gdalinfo input.tif` and  `gdalinfo output.tif`.  Additionally, please run your `gdal_translate etc...` command from the command prompt, not from python, just to assist with debugging (and include the output). Once you get the command working, you can go back to using it from python.

Comment: On a side note, os.system is being depreciated https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2010-July/102427.html, consider using subprocess.Popen(['gdal_translate', '-projwin', '3046477.80', '4645536.98', '3046546.08', '4645571.24', 'input.tif', 'output.tif']).wait() instead https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.